# Mr. Jones owns 4 pairs of pants, 7 shirts, and 3 sweaters.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In how many ways may he choose 2 of the pairs of pants, 3 of the shirt, and 1 of the sweaters to pack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He can choose 2 pairs of pants in $\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!}=6$ ways, 3 of the shirts in $\binom{7}{3}=35$ ways and one of the sweather in 3 ways, complexively he can pack in $6*35*3=630$ ways

Answer (score 0):

There are C(4,2) = 6 ways to choose 2 pairs of pants.

There are C(7,3) = 35 ways to choose 3 shirts.

There are C(3,1) = 3 ways to choose a sweater.

So in total there are: 6*35*3 = 630 ways to pack.

Comment: i think it should be 6*35*3=630...

Comment: @wanderer: it was a typo on the 1